# Hang on "running" in XCode 4.3.2, Never reaches main(), No Crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, freeze

Im having a strange problem with XCode. Im running my application but it never reaches the main() function although it says running as the status.

When I delete the app from the device, its copied over successfully. But it never attempts to run.

Also note if I try to run directly by tapping the app on the device, it brings up a black screen and flicks off straight away.

I have been playing with the ViewController/AppDelegates with no success.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Could be a stack overflow, e.g. due to large local variable allocations in main() ?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i tried to run several calculations in quick succession one after another in my method. The app just stopped there showing a black screen. Check your method for any calculations which may get exponentially larger or more complex.

Comment: This cant be the issue, it never reaches Main()